# Writing a text file using request in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying to read a txt file from a URL and output my own text file using nodejs

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong in my code?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var stream = fs.createWriteStream("my_file.txt");



request('http://redsismica.uprm.edu/Data/prsn/EarlyWarning/Catalogue.txt', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

    firstLine = body.substring(0, body.indexOf('\n'));
    console.log(firstLine);

    stream.once('open', function(fd) {
    wstream.write(firstLine, 'utf16le');//stream.write(firstLine);
    stream.end();
});
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what `wstream` is in your code but with [`request` you can pipe your response directly to your write stream.](https://github.com/request/request#streaming)

```
var stream = fs.createWriteStream('my_file.txt', { defaultEncoding: 'utf16le' });

stream.once('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});

stream.once('end', function() {
  console.log('response written');
});

request('http://redsismica.uprm.edu/Data/prsn/EarlyWarning/Catalogue.txt')
  .once('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Request Error: ' + err);
  })
  .pipe(stream);
```